# How can I access a datagrid item via binding in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I need to bind the property `SelectedItem` of a datagrid called `dg_item` in the class `ItemList` to a textbox in the page `ItemViewMenu`.
I have declared the DataContext in in the `ItemViewMenu` class as followed:

```
ItemViewMenu Menu = this;
ItemList List = PageResources.ItemListInstance;
this.DataContext = new { Menu, List };
```

This is the `PageResources.ItemListInstance`:

```
class PageResources
{
    private static ItemList _itemListInstance;
    public static ItemList ItemListInstance
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_itemListInstance == null)
                _itemListInstance = new ItemList();
            return _itemListInstance; 
        }
    }
}
```

The `dg_item` datagrid contains a list from the type `Item` which contains 
the following property I need to access:

```
public class Item 
{
    private string _manufacturerName;
    public string ManufacturerName
    {
        get
        {
            return _manufacturerName;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                _manufacturerName= value;
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

And I'm trying to access the Property in the "ItemViewMenu.xaml" like that:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource List.dg_item}, Path=SelectedItem}" Grid.Row="0"> 
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.7*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock x:Name="txt_manufacturer" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Manufacturer: " Margin="5,2" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="13"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="tb_manufacturer" Text="{Binding ManufacturerName}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,2" FontSize="13" IsReadOnly="True" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" MaxHeight="50" />
    ...
</Grid>
```

But this doesn't work. So how do I access the property `ManufacturerName`?

Comment: Names on controls is a code smell! How do you bind the DataGrid?

Comment: @XAMlMAX as I said the datagrid is binded to a list, to be exactly an "ObservableCollection" of the type "Item".